# Sails.js internationalization object in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, internationalization, sails.js

We are using sails.js internationalization concept for translating variables, so now I want to apply some basic HTML on our text.

Until now I have been using [`ng-bind-html` directive of AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) for the variables defined in my server controller for applying bold, italic on some text, but I am not able to use `__` or `il8n` or do same in AngularJs controller like:

```
$scope.mytext = req.__('Hello');
```

Is that possible?
Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: "Angular supports internationalizaton" is a question?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have two frameworks that provide MVC: sails and angular. Both provide translation services.
If you are using angular as an MVC, probably the best place to place translation is in the angular "V" of the MVC and you don't need sails then for anything that is not providing access to the data (RESTful APIS). For that, you can use angular-translate (http://angular-translate.github.io).

I've tried both using sailsjs and angular translation mechanisms, and I ended up deciding for angular, as it can be used not only in the html but also in controllers, services and in filters.

Final note, you should try to not use translation (which is a presentation transformation) in controllers :). I shouldn't either, but no one is perfect...